# Godaddy hosting with dynamic ip?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, godaddy, dyndns, dynamic-dns

I bought a domain name on godaddy.com let's call it `www.website.com`, but my server has a dynamic ip, how do I resolve this issue?

What I've tried:

get a dns account at dyndns.com let's call it `dns.dyndns.com`, so I set up godaddy to forward the domain to `dns.dyndns.com`.

problem: When the user goes to `www.website.com`, they see `dns.dyndns.com` in the url bar. Bad

So then I set up the forwarding on godaddy to forward with domain masking, but then the problem is now that users can't even see url paths/get queries/ or hash marks anymore!

```
`www.website.com/folder/search?id=4#ajax=4` becomes just
```

www.website.com in the url bar. bad!

What do I do?

EDIT:

Ok so, say my godaddy domain name is mysite.com and I have a dyndns account called redirect.com. I set up a cname record on www.mysite.com to go to blah.redirect.com. This works, but when I go to www.mysite.com it shows me the contents of www.redirect.com instead of the contents on blah.redirect.com, what gives?

Comment: I'd just get a static IP or get a professional solution such as shared ,VPS or dedicated. This is technically out of the scope of this site.
from the FAQ" and it is not about …Running servers at home"

Comment: I am not running a home media server, this is meant to be a publicized website, albeit in its very very early stages. However, I guess the scope of the questions is still more on the "home hosting" side, so should I ask this on super user instead? Since, at least for the time being, a static ip solution is not yet feasible, due to other constraints.

Comment: SuperUser would be an appropriate place to post a question such as this. Here at ServerFault, being geared towards production business environments, the correct answer to this question will always be "get a static or a full hosting plan". There might be some gray area for dev sites or startups, but in those cases you shouldn't be trying to redirect your domain to your dev site (tho a subdomain might be appropriate) and a static is still the best answer; and StackOverflow might be a better place for dev site questions anyway.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to move your name servers to DynDNS, set up your DNS records there, and install one of their dynamic DNS clients somewhere on your local network to keep your dynamic ip address in sync with your DNS records. I use DynDNS and host 6 web sites at home using their dynamic DNS client.

Comment: I tried this, and am waiting for dns propagation, hopefully it works

Comment: Ok so, say my godaddy domain name is mysite.com and I have a dyndns account called redirect.com. I set up a cname record on www.mysite.com to go to blah.redirect.com. This works, but when I go to www.mysite.com it shows me the contents of www.redirect.com instead of the contents on blah.redirect.com, what gives?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want domain masking, you want something like a CNAME record.  You would have to look up in GoDaddy's help about how to add it, but it's a standard DNS feature that they certainly support.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a web server at home, I'm 80% sure your router will be capable for dyndns. Check your routers manual on how to use it, by it probably involves going to 192.168.0.1, clicking DNS and entering the details for dyndns.

Now there are two things that could happen. Either you have been given a dedicated ip from dyndns that will resolve to your router (where you logged in). Put that on you're DNA record do yoursite.com. Or you have been given a free sub domain such as myfreeaccount.dyndns.org and you are being a cheap skate. Pay the money, get the dedicated IP or DnS service.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this same issue and, after finding a powershell script that did the update, I decided to create an application to automatically update the IP of the DNS records on GoDaddy, pretty much like what DynDNS does, the difference is that I don't have to pay for another service to do that for me anymore.

It's a Windows application though, hopefully it will suit you as well: https://github.com/leandrokoiti/GoDaddyDnsUpdater

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty easy in two steps

1. Setup a DynDNS account and create a host. Lets say you pick `host.hopto.org` as your site name
2. In Godaddy [go into the DNS Manager in the Godaddy Interface](http://help.godaddy.com/article/680) and edit the very first A record (should say @ in the host name column and an IP address in the "Points to" column). Change the IP address to your DynDNS domain name, eg `host.hopto.org`.
3. Change the TTL to a really low value. I would change it to half an hour to limit the lag of the IP address updating everywhere.

Hope this helps

Comment: goDaddy restricts aRecord ip to only ip addresses no domain names allowed =[

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a little python script to update the A record. It can be found in this public repo.

https://bitbucket.org/MattTYXM/godaddy_duc/src/9a4bdc6efa9d406029c49f331e1d3fa99bce8db9/godaddy_update.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default